# same notification to multiple selected users in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I am trying to implement a notification page on my website in Django. But I have a problem that how can I send the same notification to multiple users.

let suppose I have to send it to just one user.
then I can create a model of notification with

```
noti = models.TextField()
user= models.foreignkey
is_seen = models.bool
```

so this is just a sample
but the the problem is this how i can send this notification to selected multiple users

one important is that is_seen is compulsory for each user

I hope you will understand

Comment: with this model, just create a new instance with the same text for each user? will that be enough for your requirements?

Comment: To send a real-time notification to users you will have to use Django channels, where the servers would send data to the client without the client asking for it.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends how this data will grow in future. Because if all of your notifications go to multiple users, you can have a `Notification` model with ManyToMany relation with `User`. Something like following

```
class Notification(models.Model):
    message = models.TextField()
    users = models.ManyToMany(User, through='UserNotification')


class UserNotification(model.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    notification = models.ForeignKey(Notification)
    is_seen = models.BooleanField()
```

But other question is if you want to build something like the one you shared, that is also fine. I don't think so there's an issue of adding same message for multiple users. This is more flexible in my opinion as compared to M2M relation. You can extend this in future easily as your application will grow.

```
class Notification(model.Model):
    message = models.TextField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    is_seen = models.BooleanField)
```

Another case can be if you want to have more relations and if there's need of adding more information related to notification. This gives more room for improvement in future in terms of storing information.

```
class Notification(models.Model):
    message = models.TextField()


class UserNotification(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    notification = models.ForeignKey(Notification)
    is_seen = models.BooleanField()
```